# Migrate deployment from Jboss4.2.3 to jboss5.1AS

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

I am trying to migrate my project from jboss4 (which was build by ant) to Jboss5(exploded version)
The structure at the jboss5 will be as the wizard at eclipse "Enterprise application project"

1. I moved all servlets to the Web project.
2. fixed all build path.

When I run my project on jboss 5.0 I get the following exception:

> 13:16:28,453 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/WMA_EXPLODED.ear/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/WMA_EXPLODED.ear/WMA_EXPLODEDEJB.jar/
>       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
>       at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
>       at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
>       at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBinding.factory()
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:728)
>       at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.(AnnotationType.java:99)
>       at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:66)
>       at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:202)
>       at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
>       at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
>       at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3072)
>       at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.finder.DefaultAnnotationFinder.getAnnotation(DefaultAnnotationFinder.java:38)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.ejb.jboss.StatefulProcessor.create(StatefulProcessor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.ejb.jboss.StatefulProcessor.create(StatefulProcessor.java:44)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.ejb.jboss.AbstractEnterpriseBeanProcessor.process(AbstractEnterpriseBeanProcessor.java:90)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.ejb.jboss.AbstractEnterpriseBeanProcessor.process(AbstractEnterpriseBeanProcessor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.AbstractCreator.process(AbstractCreator.java:154)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.AbstractCreator.processMetaData(AbstractCreator.java:87)
>       at org.jboss.metadata.annotation.creator.ejb.jboss.JBoss50Creator.create(JBoss50Creator.java:109)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processJBossMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:134)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:84)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:177)
>       at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
>       ... 30 more

any idea?
Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the key part:

> `java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError`: Invalid default: `public abstract java.lang.Class org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBinding.factory()`

This is part of `jboss-annotations-ejb3.jar`, I think. Does your application bundle this JAR in its `lib` directory?  If so, try removing it, it may be clashing with JBoss5's own version.

Comment: You were right. but now it leaded me to another exception: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying WMA_EXPLODEDEJB.jar: Exception while processing container metadata for EJB: ActivityDaoBean in unit: WMA_EXPLODEDEJB.jar. ActivityDaoBean is stateless

Answer (score 0):

If you included the 4.2.3 jboss files in your project, remove those and replace them with the 5.1 ones. Also 4.2.3 runs on both JDK 1.4 and JDK 1.5 where 5.1 runs on 1.5 and 1.6 so you want to check your code for compatability with those java versions.

Found a decent [journal of migrating](http://venugopaal.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/jboss405-to-jboss-5ga/)

Comment: Thanks.  the only thing I didnt manage to fix yet is the queues:Unable to reconnect org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@11669f2(ra=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter@2a4ec6 destination=mailSenderQueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue tx=true durable=false reconnect=10 provider=java:/DefaultJMSProvider user=null maxMessages=1 minSession=1 maxSession=15 keepAlive=60000 useDLQ=true DLQHandler=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.GenericDLQHandler DLQJndiName=queue/DLQ DLQUser=null DLQMaxResent=5)
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: mailSenderQueue not bound